# Realm Swift fails in offline mode

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

I have updated Realm (RealmSwift) in my application from Beta 10.5.1 and since this migration, my app is not working offline - actually it shows no data at all, resulting in crashing my app.
Previously it was working fine.

I read through this thread, where I think the same problem is discussed, but I still could not find a solution, maybe I'm mixing up some basic logic here with login and opening a realm... https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/realm-swift-tutorial-failing-offline-first-usage/14136

I am using one email/password login and the authentication is not done via Realm, so I have one email and password combination which I use in every client.

Basically, if I'm online everything works fine, if I open the app offline, we have a problem, it does not use the local realm (which I expect as it was the case before).

```
let app = App(id: Constants.REALM_APP_ID)

app.login(credentials: Credentials.emailPassword(email: Constants.REALM_USERNAME, password: Constants.REALM_PASSWORD)) { (result) in
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Failed to log in: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        case .success(let user):
            Constants.REALM = try! Realm(configuration: user.configuration(partitionValue: Constants.REALM_PARTITION_KEY))
            Constants.REALM_LOADED = true

            let recipes = Constants.REALM.objects(Recipe.self)
            Constants.REALM_NOTIF_TOKEN_RECIPES = recipes.observe { _ in
                if (Auth.UserData.user != nil && Auth.UserData.user!.isPremium) {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: Constants.NS_RELOAD_PREMIUM_PHOTOS), object: nil) // Will invoke NS_RECIPE_CUD
                } else {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: Constants.NS_RECIPE_CUD), object: nil)
                }
            }
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: selectorName), object: nil)
        }
        viewController?.removeSpinner()
    }
}
```

My code which was working in beta:

```
let app = RealmApp(id: Constants.REALM_APP_ID)

app.login(withCredential: AppCredentials(username: Constants.REALM_USERNAME, password: Constants.REALM_PASSWORD)) { user, error in
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        if let user = app.currentUser() {
            Constants.REALM = try! Realm(configuration: user.configuration(partitionValue: user.identity!))
            viewController?.removeSpinner()
            Constants.REALM_LOADED = true

            let recipes = Constants.REALM.objects(Recipe.self)
            Constants.REALM_NOTIF_TOKEN_RECIPES = recipes.observe { _ in
                if (Auth.UserData.user != nil && Auth.UserData.user!.isPremium) {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: Constants.NS_RELOAD_PREMIUM_PHOTOS), object: nil) // Will invoke NS_RECIPE_CUD
                } else {
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: Constants.NS_RECIPE_CUD), object: nil)
                }
            }
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: selectorName), object: nil)
        } else {
            fatalError("Couldn't connect/log in to Realm")
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 1: Tried again with app.login and then asyncOpen. While the app is online, I nicely get all the data I want. Once I close the app, go offline and open again, I have no data received. I would have expected that it will read from the local device, offline. The code:

```
let app = App(id: Constants.REALM_APP_ID)

app.login(credentials: Credentials.emailPassword(email: Constants.REALM_USERNAME, password: Constants.REALM_PASSWORD)) { (result) in
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Failed to log in: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        case .success(let user):
            let configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: Constants.REALM_PARTITION_KEY)
            Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: configuration) { result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Failed to open realm: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .success(let realm):
                    Constants.REALM = realm
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When tracing out it goes into the app.login > .failure branch, and the error is: `The Internet connection appears to be offline.`

Edit 2: Tried using try! Realm if the app.currentUser is set (I assume it means that the realm is locally available as the user has previously logged in while it was online). But still, I get a crash in the app as no data is fetched/read.

```
let app = App(id: Constants.REALM_APP_ID)

if let user = app.currentUser {
    // I enter here when the app is offline but actually my data is not fetched.
    let configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: Constants.REALM_PARTITION_KEY)
    Constants.REALM = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
    viewController?.removeSpinner()
} else {
    app.login(credentials: Credentials.emailPassword(email: Constants.REALM_USERNAME, password: Constants.REALM_PASSWORD)) { (result) in
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Failed to log in: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            case .success(let user):
                let configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: Constants.REALM_PARTITION_KEY)
                Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: configuration) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("Failed to open realm: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    case .success(let realm):
                        Constants.REALM = realm
                    }
                    viewController?.removeSpinner()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things: There is no 'mode' as such. If you only access realm like this `let realm = try! Realm()` then you are using a local file - typically called default.realm. If you use Realm Sync there are *always* local files along with the data sync'd to the cloud. Realm is an offline first database. Second thing is the code in your question may have worked but that's not how to connect to MongoDB Realm Sync. You should always start with `Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: configuration) { result in...` which is outlined in the [Sync Guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/ios/sync-data/#sync-data)

Comment: For clarity - when using MongoDB Realm Sync, there will typically be several files located on your drive (or Device) - one file per partition. So if you have a User model that has a _partitionKey = "User" the file will be called something like *%22User%22.realm*. If your Task object uses the _partitionKey = "Task" the local file will be called *%Task.%22realm*

Comment: Thank you @Jay for the help. You say I should start with asyncOpen (or open, according to the Sync Guide as I understood: try! Realm()). But the code on Sync Guide is misleading for me. It says // Log in... and then asyncOpen, you say I should use asyncOpen first. As I see I log in and then open the realm.

Comment: Those are two different tasks. Authentication is where your app 'logs in' a user. Then to access Realm you would use .asyncOpen.

Comment: I just noticed your question states *I am using one email/password login and the authentication is **not done via Realm***. So... if you're not authenticating via Realm then this code would not work `app.login(credentials: Credentials.emailPassword` as that's how you would authenticate with Realm.

Answer (score 1):

After several tries I could get it working properly.

```
viewController?.showSpinner(onView: viewController!.view)
let app = App(id: Constants.REALM_APP_ID)

app.login(credentials: Credentials.emailPassword(email: Constants.REALM_USERNAME, password: Constants.REALM_PASSWORD)) { (result) in
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            // Might be because of no internet connection!
            print("Failed to log in: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            if let user = app.currentUser {
                // If the user was logged in before, we use its configuration value.
                let configuration = user.configuration(partitionValue: Constants.REALM_PARTITION_KEY)
                Constants.REALM = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
            }
        case .success(let user):
            Constants.REALM = try! Realm(configuration: user.configuration(partitionValue: Constants.REALM_PARTITION_KEY))
        }
        viewController?.removeSpinner()
    }
}
```

Comment: Change this `Constants.REALM = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)` as you need to initially connect with .asyncOpen. Check out the code in the Getting Started guide as that code works and will property synchronize your initial realm data. [Enable Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/ios-swift/#enable-authentication). You should also move the `user = app.currentUser` outside of the authentication method as if they are already authenticated you don't need to run that code again.

Comment: I tried moving the app.currentUser outside and it did not work, see my Edit 2. And there I also used your proposed asyncOpen. Isn't it what you meant?

Comment: "It did not work" is a bit vague and we don't know what the crash was. That being said, the code in both Edit 2 and this answer are not connecting using .asyncOpen the first time when a user object exists. The other issue is that `app` is a local var and could be going out of scope. See the docs [Connect](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/ios-swift/#connect-to-your-mongodb-realm-app) which shows how to *declare a global Realm App instance*. I would re-read the docs and follow the process shown there as it works.